# How do I add a head/title to each row in a table using jade?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html-table, pug

I want each row to have a separate title/header in my table without a main header, I am using java/jade/bootstrap.
Here is my current code:

```
body
table.table.table-hover.table.table-bordered
  each network, i in adlist
    tr
      td #{network.service}
      td
        a(href='/manage/network/edit/#{network.id}') #{network.name}
      td #{network.format}
      td #{network.countries}
      td #{network.weight}
```

I would like the title on the top of the column, not repeated on each row.

Answer (score 0):

*I am copying the solution here for completeness.*

Op solved the question by doing this

```
body
    table.table.table-hover.table-bordered
      thead
        tr
          th Service
          th Name
          th Format
          th Countries
          th Weight
      each network, i in adlist
        tr
          td #{network.service}
          td
            a(href='/manage/network/edit/#{network.id}') #{network.name}
          td #{network.format}
          td #{network.countries}
          td #{network.weight}
```